# JQ join two arrays

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to parse some json output from an API. I've got two arrays like this:

```
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 100.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-01T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      },
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 100.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-02T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      },
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 97.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-03T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      }
    ],
    "metadatavalues": []
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 69.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-01T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      },
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 72.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-02T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      },
      {
        "average": null,
        "count": null,
        "maximum": 71.0,
        "minimum": null,
        "timeStamp": "2020-09-03T00:30:00+00:00",
        "total": null
      }
    ],
    "metadatavalues": []
  }
]
```

I'd like to take timestamp from the "data" in the first array, and join it with the maximum value from the first and the second array, like this:

```
"2020-09-01T00:30:00+00:00", 100, 69
"2020-09-02T00:30:00+00:00", 93, 72
"2020-09-03T00:30:00+00:00", 97, 71
```

What I've got now is `jq -c [.[0].data[].timeStamp, .[0].data[].maximum, .[1].data[].maximum]` that returns everything in one array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `transpose` makes for a compact solution:

```
[.[] | .data]
| transpose[]
| [.[0].timeStamp, (.[]|.maximum)]
| @csv
```

With the given input, the output, however, would be:

```
"2020-09-01T00:30:00+00:00",100,69
"2020-09-02T00:30:00+00:00",100,72
"2020-09-03T00:30:00+00:00",97,71
```